# Unable to install git - Access Denied Error

Tags: git, installation

I want to install git.

But getting the following error -

```
  Setup was unable to create the directory  "C:\Program Files\Git\dev"

  Error5: Access is denied.
```

Answer (score 2):

For me (using Windows 10 Pro), the solution was to ***run the installer as administrator***.

#### More Detail

Before running the installer successfully as admin, I ran the installer using my regular, non-admin user profile.  After asking me many questions about installation preferences, the Git installer finally prompted me to enter admin credentials to continue.  I did so, but then I got the error this question is about.

So for some reason, Git is more finicky than every other installer I've ever encountered.  With Git, you must proactively run the installer as admin instead of waiting for it to ask you to log in as admin mid-installation.